# How to test a method that takes Class<T>

Tags: java, generics

am working on a Jenkins plugin and evaluating unit testing software at the same time, and came upon a learning opportunity.  The software wrote a test case for this method-

```
    public boolean isApplicable(Class<? extends AbstractProject> aClass) {
        // indicates that this builder can be used with all 
        // kinds of project types
        return true;
    }
```

Seems pretty straightforward.  The test case doesn't compile though, and I have not been able to figure out how to fix it from my limited knowledge of using wildcards.  My current attempt-

```
    AbstractProject ap = new FreeStyleProject(null, null);;
    Assert.assertTrue(testedObject.isApplicable(ap));
```

(FreeStyleProject extends AbstractProject)

This gives the error message

The method isApplicable(Class) in the type FitnesseBuilder.DescriptorImpl is not applicable for the arguments (AbstractProject)

I have tried a variety of types to pass to that argument, but cannot seem to get it to accept anything.  Anyone feel like giving me a quick lesson?

Comment: Thanks a ton, that cleared it up for me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the `Class<T>` object, not an *instance* of that class:

```
// AbstractProject ap = new FreeStyleProject(null, null);
Assert.assertTrue(testedObject.isApplicable(FreeStyleProject.class));
```

Of course, `FreeStyleProject` class needs to extend `AbstractProject` (since the first line of your current code compiles, it does that already).

Answer (score 4):

Try `Assert.assertTrue(testedObject.isApplicable(FreeStyleProject.class));` as it takes an instance of Class rather than AbstractProject